# Plotting function in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a simple function I wrote:

```
function f = G(s)
    f = 16/(s.^2+3*s+16)
endfunction
```

I want to plot this transfer function from s = 0 to 4 with a step of 0.01. For some reason I can't get it to work. I am getting nonconformant arguments errors. I am new to octave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dot was missing. It is mandatory when you want an element by element operation like (`./`).
See the difference between `x / y` and `x ./ y` in https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html.

```
function G = G(s)
    G = 16./(s.^2+3*s+16);
endfunction
s_ = 0:0.01:4;
plot(s_, G(s_))
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is a transfer function, then you want to use the `control` package to get a Bode plot rather than plotting it as a function, which don't really make sense (`s` being complex):

```
>> G = tf(16,[1 3 16])

Transfer function 'G' from input 'u1' to output ...

            16
 y1:  --------------
      s^2 + 3 s + 16

Continuous-time model.
>> bode(G)
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I want the step response so I used step(G). Then I wanted the step info similar to how matlab would give it. I also needed the bandwidth. Which packages would I use for this?

Comment: If you mean `stepinfo`, there isn't an equivalent in Octave, you'll have to compute the info yourself from the data returned from the `step` function.